# tinkerpop gremlin clear console not working

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

i'm a newbie to tinkerpop gremlin. querying neptune DB using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console

> gremlin> :c
>
> gremlin> :clear

is not clear the screen / console as "cls" command clears the screen in windows cmd. Please comment / give suggestions to clear the gremlin console

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there is no easy way to clear the screen. On Linux and on Mac OS X typing CTRL-L will clear the screen.

`:c` and `:clear` will reset the terminal after a query fails with an error or is asking for more input and you want to abort the query.

**Edited to add:**

If the Gremlin console is in local mode (in other words you type `:remote console` to put it into local mode) you can do this:

```
gremlin> def cls() {
......1> for (a in 1..50) println " " }
```

then typing `cls()` will clear the screen

**Edited again to add:**

On more recent Windows 10 updates try this command in the Gremlin Console when in local mode.

```
println("\033[H\033[2J")
```

Or if your are already connected to the remote server try just entering the string on its own.

```
"\033H\033[2J\033[H"
```

Comment: i saw ur comment in google groups
**gremlin> "cmd /c cls".execute()** which also didn't help

Comment: Most legacy Windows Terminals do not recognize the ANSI VT sequences. So when the CLS issues <ESC>27 - The Windows clear screen escape sequence - you just get a symbol printed. I added another option to the answer. Note that after the `.execute()` you would need to add`.text` to see the text.

Comment: No bro, its not working. I tried the following **gremlin> "cmd /c cls".execute().text**

Comment: @venkat Did you try the escape sequence I added to the answer? I have tested that on Mac, Linux and Windows 10 and it worked on all 3.

Comment: **gremlin> println("\033[H\033[2J")** //not working
**gremlin> "\033H\033[2J\033[H"** // not working

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. Several other people have tried it and confirmed it works. What version of Windows are you using and which command shell?

Comment: windows 10, tinkerpop gremlin console. Okay that's fine. i need to know one in gremlin query. Any idea about **.promise()** which returns the **completableFuture** of the query result. I need to get true if query success else false? I tried **promise(Traversal::hasNext())**. but it works for single vertex **g.V('id-1').promise(Traversal::hasNext())** returns true, when i use **g.V('id-1','id-2').promise(Traversal::hasNext())** it still returns **true** rather than **false** since **id-2** is not available in db. any idea to return false on any of the id's didn't exist?

Comment: Please make that a separate post. Thanks. That way more folks can find it.

Comment: Thanks for ur time too :)